# Moving an image towards its direction?

Tags: java, android, image, rotation

I'm a relatively young java developer. I don't know much geometry yet. I need to know what the algorithm is (in code form) to move an object towards the direction it is rotated in. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Learning basic geometry/basic vector math would help a lot i.e. http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm)

If your direction is some sort of vector - just offset current position by corresponding x and y components (potentially scaled).

If you direction is by angle - use sin/cos to compute offsets and scale:

```
    x = speed * cos (angleRadians);
    y = speed * sin (angleRadians);
```

To transform degrees to radians - divide by PI.

Comment: Thats kinda where I'm lost at. I have no trouble until I need to get the 'cos' and 'sin'. can you please explain to me how to do so? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Look at the Math package built into java.  That can calculate the cos or sin for you.  You need to give it the angle though - which you have to figure out based on how you know the direction it is rotated into.

Comment: Alright, Now this is what I've done.

              double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(player.getRotation());

but now its moving weirdly